# react-select: How to integrate the results of map function to the options of react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Can someone help me understand the mistake I am making? Because in the react-select box the options are not showing but when I print the selected option it doesn't give me the undefined value, in fact, it gives me the correct answer.

```
 <Card.Body>
                       
{ Object.entries(this.state.liste).map( ([key,valuee]) => 
                         
                 
                        
                            <div className="row ">
                            <div className="col-xl-11">
                                    <h6 className="align-items-center float-left">{key}</h6>
                                    <div className="text-right">
                            <div className="col-md-11" style={{width: '130px',  height: '20px',top: '-20px', right: '-400px'}}>
                                
                     
        < Select name = "secondSelectt"  multi={true} options=
       {valuee} 
       onChange={this.handleChange3}  />  
       </div>
                         
                            </div>
                            <div className="progress m-t-30 m-b-20" style={{height: '1px'}}>
                                        <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar" style={{width: '0%'}} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>) }

                           
                        </Card.Body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a return statement in the `.map` method. In some cases, direct return doesn't work as expected

```
 <Card.Body>
        {
            Object.entries(this.state.liste).map(([key, valuee]) => {
                return (
                    <div className = "row" >
                        <div className="col-xl-11">
                            <h6 className="align-items-center float-left">{key}</h6>
                            <div className="text-right">
                                <div className="col-md-11" style={{ width: '130px', height: '20px', top: '-20px', right: '-400px' }}>
                                    <Select 
                                        name="secondSelectt" 
                                        multi={true} 
                                        options={valuee.map(e=>({label: e, value: e}))}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange3} 
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="progress m-t-30 m-b-20" style={{ height: '1px' }}>
                                <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar" style={{ width: '0%' }} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }) 
        }
    </Card.Body >
```

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: it's correct, it's the name of a list I extract its values from flask api

Comment: can you also add a sample valuee which you are passing to the Select component

Comment: {Q_18001: Array(2), Q_18002_Error_message: Array(3), Q_18003_is_the_app_faulty: Array(3), Q_18003_wht_error_message: Array(45), Q_18004_screen_selection: Array(14)}
Q_18001: (2) ["Yes", "No"]
Q_18002_Error_message: (3) ["No", "Yes", "E_29003"]
I have edit the post and add an image that may help you understand the case; this.state.liste is composed of questions and their own answers and i want next to each question a select box to choose the response to their questions, displaying the questions was fine ..

Comment: Hey @Houdakilani, I guess the problem is with the data you are passing. You need to pass an array of objects instead of an array which should look something like this {label: 'some label', value: 'some value'} according to the library which you are using

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: no, I have passed the data as it should be accepted but I think the problem I am facing that I am trying to display content in react-select tag that change on every iteration maybe that's the problem ..